# Facebook oauth - how to a log created user in using my apps existing auth class

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

I've got an app with an existing users infrastructure. I want to add a sign in with facebook button that allows a user to bypass login and auth through their facebook account.

At the moment user registration works, a user can click the sign in with facebook button, and the app authenticates with facebook, checks if the user already exists and if not, pulls all the info from their facebook account and creates them a new user record in my DB.

It's the login part I'm struggling with though. If a user clicks the sign in with facebook button and the email address returned from facebook exists I'd like to log that user straight in. My auth class requires a password to log a user in, but I know it can't be right to set a password based on any of the facebook user details as this could easily be guessed. I've thought about using the access token, but this changes fairly often.

I feel like a might be missing something here, so please feel free to set on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the `third_party_id` field? May be just what you're looking for.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

> A string containing an anonymous, but unique identifier for this
>   person. You can use this identifier with third-parties